# trying to read data from an endpoint and use that data to create components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

there's an endpoint which has an array of objects, each object is a "todo" object that has a "title" and boolean "checked". I am trying to put those in the page.

I have the following react component which I already ran and works fine:

```
class TodosPage extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <AddToDo></AddToDo>
                <br></br>
                <Row text11="Run" isChecked={true}></Row>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

each Row represents a "to do" you can see one prop is the "text11" and the other is the boolean "isChecked".

I am trying to read from the endpoint, iterate through the todo's and create new < Row > components based on that data I read.

I have this code which reads from the endpoint and prints those values I'm looking for (I tested on playui.io and they work:

```
function getAll() {

  fetch("https://.....", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: headers

  })
  .then(function(response){ 
    return response.json(); 
  })
  .then(function(data){ 
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      console.log(data[i]["title"])
      console.log(data[i]["checked"])
    }


  });

}
```

Basically I am trying to put those two pieces of code together and that is what I'm having difficulty with. Is there a straight forward way to achieve that?

Comment: you must put your request code in the componentDidMount or in the useEffect hook

Comment: what is "request" code?

Comment: the code you are using to get the todo list  fetch...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load your data in `componentDidMount()`, and save it to your component `state`. then you can use that data when its available in the view.

Note: for more advanced patterns, you will need to check state variable is there before attempting reference it in render, otherwise you will get reference errors.

```
class TodosPage extends React.Component {

    //setup state on your component. you can also do this in a constructor if you like
    state = {
        data:[]
    }

    // constructor(props){
        // super(props);
        // this.state= {
            // data:[]
        // }
    // }

    componentDidMount(){
        //load your data when the component mounts
        fetch("https://.....", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: headers
        })
        .then(res=>res.json()).then(data=>{ 
            //add the data to component state
            this.setState({data});
        });

    }

    render() {
        //when data loads, your component will render the rows of the data using array.map()
        return (
            <div>
                <AddToDo></AddToDo>
                <br></br>
                {this.state.data.map((row,i)=><Row text11="">{row.title}</Row>)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Please consult google and the react documentation for other such information. It is clear you are lacking understanding from react, but the knowledge for these basic things is readily available.

Comment: thanks for the long response. I'm looking into it and investigating. However why did you comment out the  constructor code?

Comment: There's a built in constructor, it's not always needed to explicitly define one unless you know why you need one.

Comment: @chris56tv to show you the alternative(legacy) way of setting up state. you can either define it on the class as i showed you, or you can do it in the constructor. i mentioned it because it seems like you are brand new to react,but you showed enough effort in your question i decided to help you =P